# Twitter bootstrap TD no padding

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button

For one of my projects I need to make one button full width/height of the TD. I tried setting the normal .btn-warning with -Xpx!important but didn't work.

Currently I have this:

[image]

But want to achieve to this:

[image]

I'm using the following code:

```
<tbody>                                                         
<tr>
<td class="td-btn"><a href="#" class="btn-sm btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></a></td>
<td><a href="#">Projectnaam</a></td>    
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Does anyone know how to get this button full with/height with the TD without spacing?

Comment: please paste ur code in js fiddle so that ill help u

Comment: Bootstrap have a class for half padding: ".table-condensed". For no padding at all you have to customize bootstrap or add a own class with "padding: 0"

Comment: The markup you have posted in your question by itself produces just what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/qtf54zdx/

Comment: @faizphp sorry don't know how to include the bootstrap CSS (it's a large list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Friend of mine helped out:

```
<td style="padding: 0px;">
<a href="#" class="btn-sm btn btn-success" style="height: 44px;padding: 12px 10px;">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
</a>
</td>
```

It's almost what I want =). Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

```
.table-condensed>thead>tr>th,
.table-condensed>tbody>tr>th,
.table-condensed>tfoot>tr>th,
.table-condensed>thead>tr>td,
.table-condensed>tbody>tr>td,
.table-condensed>tfoot>tr>td {
    padding: 5px;
}
```